# How the service module of springcloud multi-module project calls other micro-services

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud

I have a multi module maven-spring project. Following is the structure

```
ParentService
---web
---service
---mapper
```

I have application class in web 
I use eureka and write some controller class in web

```
@SpringBootApplication()
@MapperScan(basePackages = {xxx})
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
@EnableEurekaClient
@EnableTransactionManagement(proxyTargetClass = true)
public class FrontApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
```

Now I want to call another microservice in service module

I want a simple method to call another microservice like restTemplate.postForObject() or feign,but there is no springcloud in service module,Do I have to write another springcloud configuration file and application class in the service module?please give me Some suggestions.

If I call microservices directly in service module component http, I can't play the role of eureka, and I can't do load balancing.

please give me Some suggestions.
Do I need to change my project architecture?

Answer (score 0):

it will be better if you take these three modules(web,service,mapper) as separate spring boot modules with spring cloud dependencies. Scaling and load balancing will be easy.